# AES Encryption in Node.js and Decryption in Java Android

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

I used [ricmoo/aes-js](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js) to encrypt node server response,

**Cypher.js**

```
"use strict";

var aesjs = require("aes-js");
var sha256 = require("js-sha256");

const getKeyArray = function() {
  let buffer = sha256.arrayBuffer("mykey");
  let keyArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const keySize = 16;
  let arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < keySize; i++) {
    arr.push(keyArray[i]);
  }
  return arr;
};

module.exports = {
  getKey: function() {
    return getKeyArray();
  },

  encrypt: function(text) {
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(text);

    // The counter is optional, and if omitted will begin at 1
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(
      getKeyArray(),
      new aesjs.Counter(Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))
    );

    var counterArray = aesCtr._counter._counter.slice()

    var encryptedBytes = aesCtr.encrypt(textBytes);

    // To print or store the binary data, you may convert it to hex
    var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);

    var ivHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(counterArray);

    return ivHex + ":" + encryptedHex;
  },
  decrypt: function(encryptedHex) {
    let split = encryptedHex.split(":");

    // When ready to decrypt the hex string, convert it back to bytes
    var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(split[1]);

    let ivHex = split[0];

    var ivBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(ivHex);

    var counter = new aesjs.Counter(ivBytes);

    // The counter mode of operation maintains internal state, so to
    // decrypt a new instance must be instantiated.
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(getKeyArray(), ivBytes);

    var decryptedBytes = aesCtr.decrypt(encryptedBytes);

    // Convert our bytes back into text
    var decryptedText = aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decryptedBytes);

    return decryptedText;
  }
};
```

And the decryption in Java

**Cypher.java**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

class Cypher {
    private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    private static String KEY = "mykey";

    /**
     * Decrypt a given hex string,
     * @param hexString
     * @return
     */
    static String decrypt(String hexString) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

        String ivHex = hexString.split(":")[0];
        hexString = hexString.split(":")[1];

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(hexStringToByteArray(ivHex));

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getEncryptionKey(KEY), ivSpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexStringToByteArray(hexString));

        return new String(decrypted);
    }

    private static SecretKeySpec getEncryptionKey(String key) throws Exception {

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        return secretKeySpec;

    }

    static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

My question is:

1- Is this code above acceptable or it has any major issue?

2- How can I improve it?

Answer (score -2):

**Edit 2**

I have updated the question, now the code in question uses random IV in the encryption & decryption process.

**Edit**

Please do not use the code below, because it doesn't generate the IVs randomly, see the comments below.

**Old Answer**

It was not easy at all, but finally I got it to work, here is my full working code (encryption on node.js and decryption on Android):

**Cypher.js**

```
"use strict";

var aesjs = require("aes-js");
var sha256 = require("js-sha256");

const getKeyArray = function() { // decryption on Android doesn't support 256 bit keys with AES/CTR, so I'm using only 128 bits
  let buffer = sha256.arrayBuffer("mystrongkey");
  let keyArray =  new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const keySize = 16;
  let arr = new Array;
  for (var i = 0; i < keySize; i++) {
    arr.push(keyArray[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}

module.exports = {
  getKey: function() {
    return getKeyArray();
  },
  getIV: function() {
    return new aesjs.Counter(5);
  },
  encrypt: function(text) {
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(text);

    // The counter is optional, and if omitted will begin at 1
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(getKeyArray(), this.getIV());
    var encryptedBytes = aesCtr.encrypt(textBytes);

    // To print or store the binary data, you may convert it to hex
    var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
    return encryptedHex;
  },
  decrypt: function(encryptedHex) {
    // When ready to decrypt the hex string, convert it back to bytes
    var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(encryptedHex);

    // The counter mode of operation maintains internal state, so to
    // decrypt a new instance must be instantiated.
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(getKeyArray(), this.getIV());
    var decryptedBytes = aesCtr.decrypt(encryptedBytes);

    // Convert our bytes back into text
    var decryptedText = aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decryptedBytes);
    return decryptedText;
  }
};
```

**Cypher.java**

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

class Cypher {
    private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    private static String KEY = "mystrongkey";

    /**
     * Decrypt a given hex string,
     * 08768efebc = Hello
     * @param hexString
     * @return
     */
    static String decrypt(String hexString) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[] { // got this one by console.log(Cypher.getIv()) from Cypher.js
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                5
        });

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getEncryptionKey(KEY), ivSpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexStringToByteArray(hexString));

        return new String(decrypted);
    }

    static String encrypt(String string) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[] {
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                5
        });

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getEncryptionKey(KEY), ivSpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(string.getBytes());

        return bytesToHex(encrypted);
    }

    private static SecretKeySpec getEncryptionKey(String key) throws Exception {

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        return secretKeySpec;

    }

    static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Hope this will save time of somebody trying to decrypt from node.js

Comment: Be aware that this method of encryption does not use authentication at all.  If the ciphertext is changed in transit/while at rest, it cannot be detected in your code.  Also note that you're using plain SHA-256 as a KDF.  This is generally a poor idea.  You should use an actual KDF like PBKDF2 instead.

Comment: On top of that, and most concerning, is that you aren't randomly generating your IVs.  If you use the same key to encrypt twice, the plaintext of both can be trivially retrieved from the two ciphertexts by XORing them together.  You might want to read more about the implications of CTR mode.  The code you have is actually seriously flawed and can easily be broken.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'm really new to this stuff, I just wanted to encrypt my response on node.js and decrypt it on my mobile clients.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I have updated the question, can you please add your answer?

Comment: Wait so are you using this to encrypt data in transit between your app and server?  Doesn't that mean the encryption key is present on any device that has your app?  Why are you not using HTTPS/TLS?

Comment: I'm using https, however, I want to make it difficult to get the response by replicating the endpoint URL, I know it is still possible for a third party to decrypt my api response since the encryption key is hardcoded on client's device, but it is not easy as querying the endpoint. Implementing oAuth2 authentication flow on client device with https is also secure, however, I thought it would be easier for the front end team to implement the decryption instead of the authorization, but apparently .. it wasn't. @LukeJoshuaPark

Comment: and yes the encryption key is present on any device that has my app .... @LukeJoshuaPark

Comment: You're solving this problem the complete wrong way.  Consider that I, as a user, can simply retrieve the symmetric key from your client app and decrypt any response I want from your endpoint.  I suggest you open a new question asking about the actual problem you are trying to solve, not the method you think is the correct way to solve it!  Link it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180025/discussion-between-mohammad-walid-and-luke-joshua-park).